# latexmk separate build directory

Tags: bibtex, ubuntu, linux, latexmk

I'm trying to use `latexmk` for the first time in Ubuntu. My project directory is the following:

- Project

  - src
  - build
  - images

In the `src` directory are the `.tex` and `.bib` files. I want the `.aux`, `.bbl`, `.log` etc. files to go into the build directory.

In the root directory I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -gt 0 ];then
    if [ $1 = "-c" ];then
        cd build
        latexmk -c ../src/poly-paper.tex
    fi
else
    cd build
    latexmk -pdf ../src/poly-paper.tex
    mv poly-paper.pdf ..
fi
```

The problem is that using this script causes it to not find the bibliography. My `latexmk` is v4.24 and doesn't support the `-auxdir` commands and I have to do without it so that someone else can compile it too.

Could someone suggest a solution please?

**EDIT:** I didn't know `latexmk` is a simple script, so I installed the newest version but I have problems using the `-auxdir` and `-outdir` commands. The problems is that Ubuntu comes with TexLive 2009 which does not support the `-output-directory` for `pdflatex`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) The current version of latexmk is 4.35. Maybe an update will help.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, some other people besides me will want to build the project and I can't force all of them to update.

Comment: latexmk is a single selfcontained script, so you could even include a copy of it in your project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the underlying `latex` command doesn't support the `-output-directory` option, then `latexmk`'s `-outdir` option won't work.

A simple solution with the scripts you are using would be to set the BIBINPUTS environment variable to include the source directory, e.g.,

```
export BIBINPUTS=:../src
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to John's answer, it could be noted that you don't need to have a separate script.  I use the following `latexmkrc` to compile everything in `_build`; this is greatly simplified by the fact that I have a single target.

```
system ("mkdir -p _build; ln -f -s ../src/main.tex _build/main.tex");
$ENV{'TEXINPUTS'}='../src:../lib:../img:';
$ENV{'BIBINPUTS'}='../src:';

@default_files = ('_build/main.tex');
$do_cd = 1
```

This works even with TeXlive, since it doesn't rely on additional options of the LaTeX binary.

Comment: A universal solution (that works also with Windows) uses `;` instead of `:` to join paths in `TEXINPUTS` and `BIBINPUTS`...

Comment: Do symbolic links work in Windows nowadays?

Comment: When modifying TEXINPUTS, better use `ensure_path`. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/474915/52414 Even then, setting TEXINPUT in this way didn't work for me. I got rid of the TEXINPUTS and `$do_cd = 1;` lines (the latter of which misses a `;`) and now it works!