# How to suitably configure the TEXINPUTS variable in latexmkrc for detecting the sty and cls files present in a custom folder in the project directory?

Tags: packages, paths, latexmk

I am working on a project where in the `.cls` and `.sty` files installed by the TeX distributions are too old, but they have been patched by other users on `github`.  I wish to use these updated versions of these `.cls` and `.sty` files for my project. For various personal reasons (easy portability across computers), I do not wish to use `texmf-local` tree and wish to put them in a folder titled `custom_cls_sty_files` in the root of my project directory.

I am using `latexmk` as my build tool. Following the solution proposed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50697/how-can-i-keep-a-clean-document-folder-with-custom-cls-sty-bst-files-in-a-s/50847#50847), I tried configuring my `latexmkrc` as

```
$ENV{'TEXINPUTS'}='./custom_cls_sty_files//:' . $ENV{'TEXINPUTS'};
```

However, this broke everything. `latexmk` is not only unable to find the `.sty` and `.cls` files, it could not find even `main.tex`!

Here is an `mwe` of `main.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \doublespacing
    \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

where a local copy of `setspace.sty` is located in the folder `custom_cls_sty_files`.

Presently, I am encountering this issue on a Windows 10 machine on TL 2018. But I have a `mac` laptop at home and a `linux` machine at work where I work on this project through git/github combo. Therefore, I would like a single cross-platform `latexmkrc` file that can solve this issue (i.e. assuming that this issue arose in the first place due to OS differences)

#### Error message when trying the suggested solution

```
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at (eval 17) line 59, <GEN0> chunk 1.
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 25 October 2018, version: 4.61.
Latexmk: applying rule 'lualatex'...
Rule 'lualatex': Rules & subrules not known to be previously run:
   lualatex
Rule 'lualatex': The following rules & subrules became out-of-date:
      'lualatex'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'lualatex'
------------
------------
Running 'lualatex  -recorder  "main.tex"'
------------
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.07.0 (TeX Live 2018/W32TeX)
 restricted system commands enabled.
! I can't find file `main.tex'.
<*> main.tex

(Press Enter to retry, or Control-Z to exit)
Please type another input file name:
```

Comment: first off relative directories should be relative to main thus AFAIK  `./custom_cls_sty_files//` would need to be a subfolder of where the .tex is which may constantly change and not work always as expected & certainly above will not work like that on windows even if working on mac or nix since windows uses different separators.  When you say across computers do you mean cross-platform which would require at least two different approaches or do you mean across flavours of Windows since if that is the case the approach will be different to the one you are pursuing. Please EDIT/clarify question

Comment: @KJO I did not fully understand your comment about the relative directory? This `custom_cls_sty_files` is just a folder in my project's root where all the `sty` and `cls` files exist. For the 2nd part of the comment, I have updated the question to clarify what I meant by cross-platform.

Comment: Also if later on you don't want to use those custom stuff you'll need to update your latexmkrc. I'd recommend something else. Learn to use custom texmf trees. Both texlive and miktex has tools to add and remove these.

Comment: @daleif I really prefer this particular approach. I know about local `texmf` trees. But I need this custom subfolder approach for archival purposes. Some package that I use are constantly changing breaking backwards compatibility with updates. I wish to use a specific version of these dependency files that can be fully controlled by me, and which will be automatically used by `latexmk` preferred over the system-wide `sty` files. This way, everything I need for reproducibility is self-contained in the project (at the expense of an increased size, of course)

Comment: You can add the folder to the personal tree so archiving shouldn’t be a problem

Comment: A few basics windows uses ; where nix and mac use : so your syntax needs to change for windows versus others. You can place the sty in the same project folder as .tex no need to mess about with varieties of // ./ \\ etc

Comment: @KJO I am already aware of this option. But placing in the root of the project won't cut it for me. I have 21 such files and don't want to clutter up my folder and github landing page with all these (I just simplified the problem for posting here).  Is there a way to detect `OS/platform` within `latexmkrc` and accordingly handle this case?

Comment: Take a look at similar question I raised and how to assign a portable texmf which was for  switching between MiKTeX and tex live but the same should work for cross-platform given two separate start up scripts https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/454384/tex-live-2017-onwards-using-texmfauxtrees-are-there-disadvantages

Comment: @KJO alright. Are we giving up `latexmkrc` based solution?  Btw, the `;` did not work too. It proceeded quite farther, but finally errored out with `! Undefined control sequence. l.40 \@writefbal           }`

Comment: In order to provide a working answer we would need to know are all the machines using tex live or MiKTeX or w32tex or  … are they installed in a similar manner on the base machine or are they switching path per invocation (user /admin) if mixed on 3 machines the solution will likely be significantly extensive hence my suggestion to just have the one personal texmf

Comment: @KJO all the machines use `TL 2018` installed as a non-root user.

Comment: Then I recommend that since 2017 you can switch  personal sty files via tlmgr conf auxtrees add =c:\wherever\mytexmf (see help files for potential uses) The main advantage is it can be redirected prior to use if necessary with other sets before calling the editor KEY point it must NOT be within the standard texmf structure but can be a separate sibling directory

Comment: @KJO Oh, that's cool. Can you please provide an example detail as an answer? Will be much useful to have the details rather than embedded in this long comment thread

Comment: Try using  `$ENV{'TEXINPUTS'}='./custom_cls_sty_files//;' . $ENV{'TEXINPUTS'};`. The colon is replaced by a semicolon, which is the correct separator for the MSWin version of TeXLive.

Comment: @JohnCollins Need to run this in `linux, mac and windows`.  can we write conditionals to detect the OS within `latexmkrc` and adjust the expression  accordingly?

Comment: @Krishna Yes. In fact, latexmk has a suitable variable already defined.  Just do `$ENV{'TEXINPUTS'}='./custom_cls_sty_files//' . $search_path_separator . $ENV{'TEXINPUTS'};`.  Better still, you can use a not-currently documented subroutine in latexmk, and write `ensure_path( 'TEXINPUTS', './custom_cls_sty_files//' );`.

Comment: @JohnCollins the `ensure_path` is brilliant and works beautifully. Can you please write this as an answer?  This is exactly what I was looking for. Quick question: If we have a directory hierarchy like `custom_cls_sty_files/pkg_1` and `custom_cls_sty_files/pkg_2`, how will the corresponding `ensure_path` invocation need to be changed?

Comment: @Krishna No change is needed.  The trailing '//' is used to indicate that subdirectories are to be searched (to all levels).  I'll make an answer, and also add `ensure_path` to the `latexmk` documentation.

Comment: @JohnCollins thank you very much. This is a wonderful solution to the problem.

Comment: See also this question →[packages - Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Latexmk actually has a subroutine for adding items to search paths.  You can write

```
ensure_path( 'TEXINPUTS', './custom_cls_sty_files//' );
```

This takes care of using the correct operating-system-dependent separator between items in the variable.  It also gracefully handles the case where the search-path variable doesn't already exist.

This subroutine is not yet documented, but it will be in the next release.

### Documentation of ensure_path

```
ensure_path( var, values ...)
```

The first parameter is the name of one of the system's environment
variables for search paths.  The remaining parameters are values that
should be in the variable.  For each of the value parameters, if it
isn't already in the variable, then it is prepended to the variable;
in that case the environment variable is created if it doesn't already
exist. For separating values, the character appropriate the the
operating system is used -- see the configuration variable
`$search_path_separator`.

Example:

```
ensure_path( 'TEXINPUTS', './custom_cls_sty_files//' );
```

(In this example, the trailing `//` is documented by TeX systems to
mean that latex, pdflatex, etc search for files in the specified
directory and in all subdirectories.)

Technically `ensure_path` works by setting Perl's variable
`$ENV{var}`, where `var` is the name of the target variable.
The changed value is then passed as an environment variable to any
invoked programs.

Comment: awesome. This is exactly what I was looking for. Upvoted & accepted.

Comment: `ensure_path()` does not exist in my version (4.41, January 2015) of `latexmk`, so I used `$ENV{TEXINPUTS} = join(":", ($ENV{TEXINPUTS} || ()), "su-thesis//");` instead.

Comment: @JohnCollins, where `ensure_path()` subroutine call should be placed? In `latexmkrc` file?

Answer (score 3):

Newer versions of Tex Live address the need for **user or project specific** sets of files to override the defaults. This should only apply to give priority to the files that are there others that are on texmf paths will be used as normal. Although untested I would NOT split a TDS package between the two locations, so you may need to duplicate in some cases package related support files so as to be found relative to each other.

This was introduced in Tex Live 2017 and is invoked by calling (irrespective of platform)

```
 tlmgr conf auxtrees [add | remove | show] <path to desired files>
```

For windows use it may be something like (avoiding spaces and accents etc.)

tlmgr conf auxtrees add C:\Users\myname\PersonalTexmf
tlmgr conf auxtrees show C:\Users\myname\PersonalTexmf

Linux or OS/X users may need to use sudo:

sudo tlmgr conf auxtrees add "./personal_texmf"

You may need to experiment with using TDS compliant folders but the related structure should be similar to within texmf-local.
see also https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-110002.3

IT is important that the aux tree is **NOT within an existing texmf** structure  (to avoid potential conflicts of priority) however the auxiliary **may be a folder alongside texmf-local**

IF texmf-local files interfere in precedence then it may become necessary to temporarily block a default texmf-local folder first via a shell script or manually commenting out via alternative copies of your current texmf.cnf

Here is a hypothetical example session from the 2017 blog

```
$ tlmgr conf auxtrees show
tlmgr: no auxiliary texmf trees defined.
$ tlmgr conf auxtrees add /projects/book-abc
$ tlmgr conf auxtrees
List of auxiliary texmf trees:
  /projects/book-abc
$ tlmgr conf auxtrees remove /projects/book-abc
$ tlmgr conf auxtrees show
tlmgr: no auxiliary texmf trees defined.
```

That was very untypical, and we may need to address the filename database /font maps for the user prior to calling Tex Live in anger.

Note at the same time there were changes to

> "The TEXMFLOCAL tree is now searched before TEXMFSYSCONFIG and
>   TEXMFSYSVAR (by default);"

The defaults should be

> "TEXMFLOCAL (by default, /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local or
>   %SystemDrive%\texlive\texmf-local on Windows) is intended for
>   system-wide local fonts and macros; and TEXMFHOME (by default,
>   $HOME/texmf or %USERPROFILE%\texmf), is for personal fonts and macros.
>   These directories are intended to stick around from release to
>   release, and have their content seen automatically by a new TEX Live
>   release. Therefore, it is best to refrain from changing the definition
>   of TEXMFLOCAL to be too far away from the main TEX Live directory, or
>   you will need to manually change future releases."

It may be useful to see the results with Kpathsea & Kpsewhich
https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-550007.1
https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-650007.2.2

Thus **after adding or removing a path to the priority order we should also call**

```
mktexlsr
```

or possibly better

```
texhash
```

Comment: Your solution worked nicely for me yesterday. Thank you for the awesome detailed answer. I hadn't heard of the `conf  auxtrees` option before. I am glad I could learning something new from your answer. John Collin's `latexmk`-based solution answers exactly my question, whilst yours provides a valuable workaround. Hope it is okay if I accept his answer. I have upvoted for your answer for its usefulness.